# How To Edit ID3 Tags Of An Audio File With Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, id3-tag

I'm working on a tag editor app in xcode. so I had some problems with writing the tags into an audio file. I can get the tags with AudioFileGetProperty() function of AudioToolbox.h framework but When I Use the Other Function AudioFileSetProperty() I Get Some Errors like : "The Operation Could Not Be Completed", etc. How Can I Handle This Error? Is there Any Framework For Editing the ID3 Tags?

Comment: What platform is this (iOS or Mac)? What kind of audio file are you working with? This might be relevant: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1676/_index.html You may want to add the code for your "set" function to your question.